# How do I get an Ascii to warp to a certain value after it has past 122?

Tags: vb.net, ascii, basic

I am trying to write an encryption program. The problem I am facing is that I am converting the text to ascii and then adding on the offset. However when it goes past the letter 'z' I want it to warp back to 'a' and go from there.

```
Sub enc()

    Text = TextBox1.Text
    finalmessage = ""
    letters = Text.ToCharArray
    offset = ComboBox1.SelectedItem

    For x = LBound(letters) To UBound(letters)
        finalmessage = finalmessage + Chr(Asc(letters(x)) + offset)
    Next

    TextBox2.Text = finalmessage

End Sub
```

Comment: this would be hard to decode then? :D how will you know how many times you warped back? ascii has 255 code set and you only want to use till Z? you would have to convert in a style of base64, first convert it to bits and then split it on your desired range

Comment: @Icepickle ASCII has 128 characters numbered from 0-127. A .NET string  (`TextBox1.Text`) has Unicode/UTF-16 code units. (PadLeft 8 in your answer should be for 16.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess to make it easy to decode afterwards, you should to it somewhat in the line of base64 encoding, first encoding everything to a normalized binary string, then encode in the range you want (since using binary, it has to be something that fits with 2^X).

To match your range, i used a baseset of 32, and a simple encoding decoding example (a bit more verbose that it should be, perhaps)

```
Module Module1

    Dim encodeChars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEF" ' use 32 as a base

    Function Encode(text As String) As String
        Dim bitEncoded As String = ""
        Dim outputMessage As String = ""
        For Each ch As Char In text.ToCharArray()
            Dim i As Integer = Convert.ToByte(ch)
            bitEncoded &= Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(8, "0"c)
        Next

        While bitEncoded.Length Mod 5 <> 0
            bitEncoded &= "0"
        End While

        For position As Integer = 0 To bitEncoded.Length - 1 Step 5
            Dim range As String = bitEncoded.Substring(position, 5)
            Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(range, 2)

            outputMessage &= encodeChars(index).ToString()
        Next

        Return outputMessage
    End Function

    Function Decode(encodedText As String) As String
        Dim bitEncoded As String = ""
        Dim outputMessage As String = ""

        For Each ch In encodedText
            Dim index As Integer = encodeChars.IndexOf(ch)
            If index < 0 Then
                Throw New FormatException("Invalid character in encodedText!")
            End If
            bitEncoded &= Convert.ToString(index, 2).PadLeft(5, "0"c)
        Next

        ' strip the extra 0's
        While bitEncoded.Length Mod 8 <> 0
            bitEncoded = bitEncoded.Substring(0, bitEncoded.Length - 1)
        End While

        For position As Integer = 0 To bitEncoded.Length - 1 Step 8
            Dim range As String = bitEncoded.Substring(position, 8)
            Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(range, 2)

            outputMessage &= Chr(index).ToString()
        Next

        Return outputMessage
    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim textToEncode As String = "This is a small test, with some special characters! Just testing..."
        Dim encodedText As String = Encode(textToEncode)
        Dim decodedText As String = Decode(encodedText)

        Console.WriteLine(textToEncode)
        Console.WriteLine(encodedText)
        Console.WriteLine(decodedText)

        If Not String.Equals(decodedText, textToEncode) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Encoding / decoding failed!")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Encoding / decoding completed succesfully!")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

this then gives the following output?

```
This is a small test, with some special characters! Just testing...
krugsCzanfzsayjaonwwcBdmebAgkCBufqqhoAlunaqhgBBnmuqhgCdfmnuwcBbamnugcCtbmnAgkCtteeqeuDltoqqhizltoruwCzzofyxa
This is a small test, with some special characters! Just testing...
Encoding / decoding completed succesfully!
```